# Batch File, Internal Routines and Conditional Processing

Tags: batch-file

Is the script snippet below valid? What I want is if `:isRunning` returns non-zero then run `:startRunning`.

```
call :isRunning %parentCntr% || call :startRunning %parentCntr%

:isRunning
set ThreadNum=Thread=%1
rem set /p continue=in isRunning with ThreadNum set to %ThreadNum%
wmic process where "name like '_progres.exe' and  commandline like '%%%tgtString%%%' and commandline like '%%%ThreadNum%%%'" | findstr "_progres"
set /p continue=isRunning errorlevel = %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b 1
exit /b 0

:startRunning
set ThreadNum=%1
set /p continue=startRunning ThreadNum is %ThreadNum%
if exist %scriptdir%\ReplBatch%ThreadNum%.bat wscript.exe %pfsdir%\invis.vbs %scriptdir%\ReplBatch%ThreadNum%.bat
set /p continue=startRunning errorlevel = %errorlevel%
exit /b 0
```

`:isRunning` executes successfully (I have checked the errorlevel at the end of the routine) but then the script goes and runs `:startRunning` immediately after returning.  Putting in a few echos and `set/p` I see the following. I do not understand why when I check the errorlevel in the subroutine and it is zero but the test on the line immediately afterwards shows it as 1.

```
proenv>set /p continue=isRunning errorlevel = 0
isRunning errorlevel = 0

proenv>if 1 NEQ 0 exit /b 1

proenv>set ThreadNum=1

proenv>set /p continue=startRunning ThreadNum is 1
startRunning ThreadNum is 1
```

Comment: Ater the `call || call` line there is nothing to stop the code flow, so it just continues with the next line (a label doesn't stop the code flow!). Put a `goto :eof` a line before the subroutines to stop the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why in the second test `%errorlevel%` is equal to 1 while in the previous test it was equal to 0 is this:

When you press ENTER at `isRunning errorlevel = %errorlevel%` the `%continue%` variable is not defined, therefore returning a 1 as `%errorlevel%`.
To make the `%errorlevel%` 0, you need to edit the script like this:

```
echo isRunning errorlevel = %errorlevel%
pause > nul
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b 1
exit /b 0
```

This way, by replacing the `set /p continue=` part with a simple `pause > nul` you won't be setting `%errorlevel%` as 1.

You can do the same thing in `:startRunning` but - since you aren't checking the `%errorlevel%` value - it is not needed.

```
echo startRunning errorlevel = %errorlevel%
pause > nul
exit /b 0
```

TL;DR: Since you were using `set /p continue=` just like a "Press any key to continue..." command, the `%continue%` variable remains undefined, therefore returning 1 as `%errorlevel%`. The solution is to replace it with a `pause` command like I did.